# parsing xml in postgres data-type in windows

Tags: postgresql, windows-8.1, libxml2

I'm using Postgres 9.3 on Windows 8.1, trying the basic xml parsing functions.
In the SQL Editor I write:

```
XMLPARSE (CONTENT 'abc<foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar>');
```

Postgres returns me the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "XMLPARSE"
LINE 1: XMLPARSE (CONTENT 'abc<foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar>');
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "XMLPARSE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Did I write something wrong?
In the docs for 9.3 it says:`Use of this data type requires the installation to have been built with configure --with-libxml.`
As I'm on windows 8.1 I have been looking in the stack builder and couldn't find the library libxml, how do I install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with your version or platform. `XMLPARSE` isn't a top level command, it's a function.

```
regress=> XMLPARSE (CONTENT 'abc<foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar>');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "XMLPARSE"
LINE 1: XMLPARSE (CONTENT 'abc<foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar>');
        ^
```

vs

```
regress=> SELECT XMLPARSE (CONTENT 'abc<foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar>');
            xmlparse             
---------------------------------
 abc<foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar>
(1 row)
```

Comment: OK, thanks, it shows up as a very beginner question, but even when reading the docs, in their first example it wasn't clear how to use it.